# Запятая между глаголами совершенного и несовершенного вида

Tags: глаголы, однородные-члены

Ставится ли запятая между глаголами совершенного и несовершенного вида, которые соединены союзом "и"? Подскажите, пожалуйста, правило, которым нужно руководствоваться.

***Общение продолжалось длительное время и было случайным.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Общение продолжалось длительное время и было случайным***.

Вообще говоря, союзом И соединяются сказуемые, а не глаголы. В частности, в этом предложении два сказуемых: продолжалось (простое глагольное) и было случайным (составное именное).

Сказуемые однородные. Запятая не ставится, если одиночный соединительный союз И связывает однородные члены. Это правило Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100

1. Между однородными членами предложения, связанными одиночными соединительными союзами и, да (в значении ‘и’), да и, запятая не ставится: Часовой дошёл до противоположного угла и повернул обратно (Ф.)

Вид глагола не имеет значения (кстати, в данном случае глаголы *продолжалось* и *было*  несовершенного вида).